# Is it possible to substring value in NodeFilter CommandLine Argument in rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I have a Rundeck job where I'm loading the `env` Option values from remote file.
File has values as shown below

`domain-dev`

In `NodeFilter` CommandLine Argument, I'm loading values as `environment: ${option.env}`

I want to do substring of the values of env till `-`. Eg: I want to give `domain` to `NodeFilter`

is it possible to do something like below

`NodeFilter = environment: ${option.env.substring(0, option.env.indexOf("-"))}`

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible in that way, but you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/11-node-filters.html#node-filter-syntax). To get values from a specific string. For `domain-dev` you can use this regex `name: ^([^-]*).*$` to get only the string before the `-` character, of course, this example uses the `tags` attribute to apply the filter.

You can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) or [freeformater](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html) to test your regex patterns.